# With pandas why does `DataFrame(foo) is foo` = False?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Starting with the example...

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

In [3]: iris = load_iris()

In [4]: X = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

In [5]: output_df = pd.DataFrame(X)

In [6]: X is output_df
Out[6]: False

In [7]: list(X.columns)
Out[7]: 
['sepal length (cm)',
 'sepal width (cm)',
 'petal length (cm)',
 'petal width (cm)']

In [8]: output_df['y'] = iris.target

In [9]: list(X.columns)
Out[9]: 
['sepal length (cm)',
 'sepal width (cm)',
 'petal length (cm)',
 'petal width (cm)',
 'y']
```

`[6]` says that `X is output_df` is `False`, meaning they are not the same object. If they are not the same object, then adding a column to one of them should not affect the other one.

However `[9]` tells us that adding a column to `output_df` definitely did add the same column to `X`, which implies they actually are the same object.

Why is there a disconnect here?

(`pd.__version__ == 0.24.1` and `python --version = Python 3.7.1`, in case it matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some decoupling between a `DataFrame` and its underlying data, which is stored in its `BlockManager`.  In your example the underlying `BlockManager` data is the same, so changing it on one `DataFrame` will impact the other:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.1'

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abc'), 'B': [10, 20, 30]})

In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)

In [4]: df is df2
Out[4]: False

In [5]: df._data is df2._data
Out[5]: True

In [6]: df._data
Out[6]:
BlockManager
Items: Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
IntBlock: slice(1, 2, 1), 1 x 3, dtype: int64
ObjectBlock: slice(0, 1, 1), 1 x 3, dtype: object
```

Essentially `DataFrame` serves as a wrapper around the underlying data, so these actually are different objects, it's just that certain components of them happen to be shared.  As a basic example, you can add dummy attributes to one without impacting the other:

```
In [7]: df.foo = 'bar'

In [8]: df.foo
Out[8]: 'bar'

In [9]: df2.foo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

To get around the issue of shared underlying data you'll need to explicitly tell the `DataFrame` constructor to copy the input data via the `copy` parameter:

```
In [10]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, copy=True)

In [11]: df._data is df2._data
Out[11]: False

In [12]: df['C'] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   A   B    C
0  a  10  1.1
1  b  20  2.2
2  c  30  3.3

In [14]: df2
Out[14]:
   A   B
0  a  10
1  b  20
2  c  30
```